# Python: AI not always placing his move in b-ship

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code of b-ship:

```
import random
import time

def drawboard(aiboard,playerboard):
    print(' Opponent\'s          Your')
    print('    Ships            Ships')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + aiboard[7] + ' | ' + aiboard[8] + ' | ' + aiboard[9] + ' |    | ' + playerboard[7] + ' | ' + playerboard[8] + ' | ' + playerboard[9] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + aiboard[4] + ' | ' + aiboard[5] + ' | ' + aiboard[6] + ' |    | ' + playerboard[4] + ' | ' + playerboard[5] + ' | ' + playerboard[6] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('-------------    -------------')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
    print('| ' + aiboard[1] + ' | ' + aiboard[2] + ' | ' + aiboard[3] + ' |    | ' + playerboard[1] + ' | ' + playerboard[2] + ' | ' + playerboard[3] + ' |')
    print('|   |   |   |    |   |   |   |')
def playerhitai(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots):
    if players_chosen_hit in aishipplaces[0] or players_chosen_hit in aishipplaces[1]:
        aiboard[players_chosen_hit] = 'x'
        drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)
    else:
        aiboard[players_chosen_hit] = 'o'
        drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)

def hitaroundhit(aiboard, playerboard,aishipplaces,players_chosen_hit,usershipspots):
    spots = {1:[2,4],2:[1,3,5],3:[2,6],4:[1,5,7],5:[2,4,6,8],6:[3,5,9],7:[4,8],8:[5,7,9],9:[8,6]}
    spot_dict = random.choice(spots[players_chosen_hit])
    if playerboard[spot_dict] == 's':
        pickX(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots)
        playerhitai(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots)
    else:
        playerboard[spot_dict] = 'o'
        playerhitai(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots)

def pickX(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots,aitakenmoves):
    x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    firsthitattempt = random.choice(x)
    while x in aitakenmoves:
        firsthitattempt = random.choice(x)
    return firsthitattempt,aitakenmoves

def aihitplayer(aiboard,playerboard, usershipspots,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,aitakenmoves):
    x,z = pickX(aiboard,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,playerboard,usershipspots,aitakenmoves)
    if (aiboard[aishipplaces[0][0]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[0][1]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][0]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][1]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][2]] == 'x'):
        return z
    else:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("\nComputer's turn.\n")
        time.sleep(1)
        if x in usershipspots:
            playerboard[x] = 'x'
            drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)
        else:
            playerboard[x] = 'o'
            drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)
    return z

def getShipInfo(ship,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard):
    while True:
        try:
            ship = int(input('Enter the 5 locations of your ship. Start with ship one (2 spaces) then do ship two (3 spaces).'))
            if ship in possibleusershipplaces:
                break
        except ValueError:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("\nInvalid entry\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)
    while ship in usershipspots:
        try:
            ship = int(input('Spot already taken.'))
            if ship not in possibleusershipplaces:
                while True:
                    try:
                        ship = int(input('1-9 only!'))
                    except (ValueError, IndexError):
                        print('invalid input')
        except (ValueError, IndexError):
            time.sleep(0.5)
            print("\nInvalid entry\n")
            time.sleep(0.5)    
    playerboard[ship] = 's'
    usershipspots.append(ship)
    return playerboard,usershipspots
def ascii():
    print('''    dMMMMb  .aMMMb dMMMMMMP dMMMMMMP dMP     dMMMMMP .dMMMb  dMP dMP dMP dMMMMb''')
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print('''   dMP"dMP dMP"dMP   dMP      dMP   dMP     dMP     dMP" VP dMP dMP amr dMP.dMP''')
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print('''  dMMMMK" dMMMMMP   dMP      dMP   dMP     dMMMP    VMMMb  dMMMMMP dMP dMMMMP" ''')
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print(''' dMP.aMF dMP dMP   dMP      dMP   dMP     dMP     dP .dMP dMP dMP dMP dMP''')
    time.sleep(0.02)
    print('''dMMMMP" dMP dMP   dMP      dMP   dMMMMMP dMMMMMP  VMMMP" dMP dMP dMP dMP''')                             
    time.sleep(1)
def playagain():
    x = input("Play again? y/n")
    if x == 'yes' or x == 'y' or x == 'Yes' or x == 'Y':
        main()
    else:
        pass
def main():
    print()
    ascii()
    print()
    time.sleep(1)
    print('''
############################################################################
# Instructions:                                                            #
# You have a 3x3 board. So does the AI.                                    #
# Each person has 2 ships. One has a length of 2, other has a length of 3. #
# You can place the ships horizantally or vertically, not diagonally.      #
# You must try to hit the AI ships. Each move you get one shot.            #
# The player and AI alternates back and forth.                             #
# A hit is X and a miss is O. Your ships are designated with an S.         #
# Whoever hits all of the other\'s ships first, wins the game.              #
############################################################################
''')
    time.sleep(5)
    print()
    aitakenmoves = []
    twoships = [[1,2], [2,1], [1,4], [4,1], [2,3], [3,2], [2,5], [5,2], [3,6], [6,3], [4,5], [5,4], [4,7], [7,4], [5,6], [6,5], [5,8], [8,5], [6,9], [9,6], [7,8], [8,7], [8,9], [9,8]]
    threeships = [[1,2,3], [1,3,2], [2,1,3], [2,3,1], [3,2,1], [3,1,2], [1,4,7], [1,7,4], [4,1,7], [4,7,1], [7,4,1], [7,1,4], [2,5,8], [2,8,5], [5,8,2], [5,2,8], [8,5,2], [8,2,5], [3,6,9], [3,9,6], [6,9,3], [6,3,9], [9,6,3], [9,3,6], [4,5,6], [4,6,5], [5,6,4], [5,4,6], [6,5,4], [6,4,5], [7,8,9], [7,9,8], [9,8,7], [9,7,8], [8,7,9], [8,9,7]]
    shipspots1 = random.choice(twoships)
    shipspots2 = random.choice(threeships)
    while (shipspots1[0] in shipspots2) or (shipspots1[1] in shipspots2):
        shipspots1 = random.choice(twoships)
        shipspots2 = random.choice(threeships)
    aishipplaces = [shipspots1,shipspots2]
    aiboard = [' ' for i in range(10)]
    playerboard = [' ' for i in range(10)]

    sh1sp1,sh1sp2,sh2sp1,sh2sp2,sh2sp3 = '','','','',''
    possibleusershipplaces = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
    players_inputted_hits = []
    usershipspots = []
    playerboard,usershipspots = getShipInfo(sh1sp1,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard)
    playerboard,usershipspots = getShipInfo(sh1sp2,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard)
    playerboard,usershipspots = getShipInfo(sh2sp1,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard)
    playerboard,usershipspots = getShipInfo(sh2sp2,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard)
    playerboard,usershipspots = getShipInfo(sh2sp3,possibleusershipplaces,usershipspots,playerboard)

    players_inputted_hits = []
    gameisplaying = True
    while gameisplaying:
        playersturn=True
        while playersturn:
            while True:
                try:
                    players_chosen_hit = int(input('Where do you want to try to hit the AI?: 1-9  '))
                    if players_chosen_hit in possibleusershipplaces:
                        if players_chosen_hit in players_inputted_hits:
                            while True:
                                try:
                                    players_chosen_hit = int(input('Already there! Try somewhere else!'))
                                    if players_chosen_hit not in players_inputted_hits:
                                        break
                                except ValueError:
                                    time.sleep(0.5)
                                    print("\nInvalid entry\n")
                                    time.sleep(0.5)
                        break
                except ValueError:
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    print("\nInvalid entry\n")
                    time.sleep(0.5)
            players_inputted_hits.append(players_chosen_hit)
            playerhitai(aiboard, players_chosen_hit, aishipplaces, playerboard,usershipspots)
            playersturn = False
        aiturn = True
        while aiturn:
            aitakenmoves = aihitplayer(aiboard, playerboard, usershipspots,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,aitakenmoves)
            aiturn = False
        if (playerboard[usershipspots[0]] == 'x') and (playerboard[usershipspots[1]]) == 'x' and (playerboard[usershipspots[2]]) == 'x' and (playerboard[usershipspots[3]]) == 'x' and (playerboard[usershipspots[4]] == 'x'):
            print("AI WINS!")
            gameisplaying = False
        elif (aiboard[aishipplaces[0][0]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[0][1]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][0]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][1]] == 'x') and (aiboard[aishipplaces[1][2]] == 'x'):
            print("PLAYER WINS!")
            gameisplaying = False
    playagain()
main()
```

The AI is not always placing his move. It may be because his chosen move `x = pickX()` is already in the `aiboard`. I have made a list `aitakenmoves` to try to alleviate this condition, but it still persists. Any assistance?

Comment: Not sure if this is related to your problem, but I'm not sure that `except ValueError or IndexError` does what it's supposed to do. I think you want `except (ValueError, IndexError)`.

Comment: Oh, thanks. @Kevin and are you able to help with the problem?

Comment: I think it may just be because you are appending x to aitakenmoves, but what you want to be appending is firsthitattempt.  However, I might not be interpreting everything correctly.  I would recommend creating and using one or two class objects and representing the board as a 3x3 2d list instead of just 1 list, although those are both just readability concerns coming from my perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is occurring in the function `pickX()` where you are trying to use the `aitakenmoves` variables. There are two issues:

1. The line

   ```
   aitakenmoves = []
   ```

   deletes your record of moves taken each time you run the function, so the first move the AI picks is always chosen, no matter what moves it has taken before.
2. The `aitakenmoves` variable is not stored in the global scope (which is probably why you decided to initialize it each time the function is called), so the variable disappears after the `pickX()` function call ends. You will either want to keep track of the `aitakenmoves` as either

   - A) a variable in the `main()` function that you pass to `aihitplayer()` which in turn passes the variable to `pickX()`. You can then pass the choice back to `main()` from `aihitplayer()` by using a multiple return as you have in other places in your code. Or
   - B) a truly global variable, initialized before you call `main()` that you then access in the `pickX()` with the line

     `global aitakenmoves`

     that you can update directly in `pickX()`.

I would personally recommend picking choice A, even though implementing choice B would definitely be easier to program since messing with `global` can be very confusing.

P.S. At least with the code given here, when the player wins, the AI still gets to take its turn.

EDIT: An abbreviated demonstration of how to implement choice A properly.

```
def pickX(aitakenmoves):
    firsthitattempt = random.randint(1, 9)
    while firsthitattempt in aitakenmoves:
        firsthitattempt = random.randint(1, 9)
    return firsthitattempt

def aihitplayer(aiboard,playerboard, usershipspots,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces, aitakenmoves):
    x = pickX(aitakenmoves)

    time.sleep(1)
    print("\nComputer's turn.\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    if x in usershipspots:
        playerboard[x] = 'x'
        drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)
        return True, x #AI makes a hit
    else:
        playerboard[x] = 'o'
        drawboard(aiboard,playerboard)
        return False, x #AI misses

def main():
    # Initialization code
    aitakenmoves = []
    while gameisplaying:
        # Game loop
        ai_hit, location = aihitplayer(aiboard, playerboard, usershipspots,players_chosen_hit,aishipplaces,aitakenmoves)
        aitakenmoves.append(location)
        # Rest of game loop
```

Comment: I fixed your p.s. thing (though i didn't post it). Also Option 1 is that I should just delete `aitakenmoves = []`?

Comment: Oh so option 1 in the second bullet

Comment: @Player72 You definitely need to remove the `aitakenmoves = []` line, but you need to fix the issues in both points 1 and 2. Point 2 can be fixed with either A or B. I apologize for making the numbering a bit ambiguous, I hope I have clarified it.

Comment: @Player72 If you wanted to, this would actually be possible, but adjusting your `aitakenmoves` to be a `global` or to be passed into the function would be a less jarring change. (If you really want to remove it, you could use the `playerboard` variable to figure where the AI has already struck.)

Comment: (i deleted my comment accidentally saying if i should've deleted all traces of `aitakenmoves`) Well i changed my mind and I'm going with option A.

Comment: @Player72 You'll want to initialize it as an empty array sometime before you enter your main game loop (`while gameisplaying:`). You would then pass it to `aihitplayer()` as a new argument, and in turn to `pickX()`. `pickX()` already passes its choice back to `aihitplayer()`, so you'll need to that to the return for `aihitplayer()` as well, and then read that in from the `main()` call of the function and append it to the list.

Comment: can you rephrase your comment starting from `so you'll need to that to the return for aihitplayer() as well, and then read that in from the main() call of the function and append it to the list.` because that part didn't make a lot of sense

Comment: do you mean `so you'll need to USE that` @bobchao87

Comment: I am confused.   @BobChao87

Comment: I think u mean `to ADD that`

Comment: Ah, yes, "so you'll need to _ADD_ that to the return for aihitplayer() as well". Apologies. Basically, your return should be like that of `getShipInfo()` where you return more than one value. (Though I note that you don't actually seem to use the boolean return type of `aihitplayer()` currently, so possibly consider replacing the return value rather than making it a tuple.)

Comment: I can't seem to do it. Can you show me how the correct way to do it would be?

Comment: I'm working on it. Example is non-trivial to write out. Also, keep in mind that SO is not a chat site; don't always expect instant responses. We are volunteers and may sometimes have to leave the site to do other things. :)

Comment: did you mean aitakenmoves.append(location)?